# Can C# be piped?

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am trying to control a program across a network using TCP and simple text commands (I will probably switch to binary data eventually).

However, I am wondering if there is a way to encode data the program is sent and send it across the network, then decode it and give it to the recipient program? My current code is below, but I am trying to find a better way than implementing this for EVERY interface in [ASCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCOM_%28standard%29). Obviously I will also have to write the server-side code to actually do the requested action. (FYI, this one is one of the smaller ones.)

I believe it uses [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) in communication. So if COM data comes in from outside (calling methods, setting properties, etc.), shouldn't there be a way to capture that data, pipe it across the network, then give it to the recipient on the other computer?

```
class SwitchConverter : ASCOM.Interface.ISwitch
{
    private Client client = new Client();
    private string query(string query){ return client.query(query); }
    private void send(string command) { client.send(command); }
    public bool Connected { get { return bool.Parse(query("SWITCHGETCONN")); } set { send("SWITCHSETCONN:" + value); } }
    public string Description { get { return query("SWITCHGETDESC"); } }
    public string DriverInfo { get { return query("SWITCHGETDRVI"); } }
    public string DriverVersion { get { return query("SWITCHGETDRVV"); } }
    public bool GetSwitch(short ID) { return bool.Parse(query("SWITCHGETSTAT:" + ID)); }
    public string GetSwitchName(short ID) { return query("SWITCHGETNAME:" + ID); }
    public short InterfaceVersion { get { return short.Parse(query("SWITCHGETINTV")); } }
    public short MaxSwitch { get { return short.Parse(query("SWITCHGETMAXS")); } }
    public string Name { get { return query("SWITCHGETNAME"); } }
    public void SetSwitch(short ID, bool State) { send("SWITCHSETSTAT:" + ID + "-" + State); }
    public void SetSwitchName(short ID, string Name) { send("SWITCHSETNAME:" + ID + "-" + Name); }
    public void SetupDialog() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

By the way, send and query are in another class which does all the communication. Very simple. You can find more info on ASCOM interfaces at the Ascom-Standards website: http://ascom-standards.org/

P.S. What about .NET Remoting?

Comment: .NET Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF.

Comment: .NET Remoting seems to have what I need with its singleton. Is WCF similar?

Comment: WCF is much better than .NET Remoting in almost every way. Remitting is pretty much obsolete, and shouldn't be used in new development if you have a choice (and you _do_ have a choice). Note the heading of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72x4h507.aspx. "Legacy technology" kept for "backwards compatibility" == "don't use it".

Comment: No, I didn't notice. Well, if anyone can explain how to do this, I would appreciate it.